# Trouble building bash array to validate uptime values from aws cli command json output

Tags: bash, command-line, aws

I'm running a command from a bash 4 prompt to gather the output from AWS CLI commands that pull the output of an AWS SSM run document. I can have it output in multiple formats including text or json (default). I am, unsuccessfully so far, attempting put this output into an array so I can loop through the output until every value in the array equals 2 or higher.

```
#!/bin/bash

aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:RebootGroup,Values=01" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text`

sleep 30

completeLoop=false

while [ ! ${completeLoop} ]
do
    ssmID=$(aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --document-version "1" --targets '[{"Key":"tag:RebootGroup","Values":["01"]}]' --parameters '{"commands":["$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem ","$uptimeMinutes = ($wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LocalDateTime)-$wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime) | select-object -expandproperty \"TotalMinutes\")","[int]$uptimeMinutes"],"workingDirectory":[""],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-west-2 --output text --query "Command.CommandId")

    declare -a a
    readarray -t upTimeArray <<< $(aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "$ssmID" --details --output json | jq '.CommandInvocations[].CommandPlugins[].Output')

    if [[ " ${upTimeArray[@]} " -gt 5 ]]; then
        echo "Uptime is greater than 5 minutes."
        completeLoop=true
    else
        completeLoop=false
    fi

done
```

I've made some progress here but now I am trying to figure out how to remove the carriage return/new line from the output.

Here is my array simplified to just output the value of the items in the array. I assume I need to use sed to strip the '\r\n' from each line but I am having trouble doing so.

```
declare -a a

readarray -t upTimeArray <<< $(aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "$ssmID" --details --output json | jq '.CommandInvocations[].CommandPlugins[].Output')

for i in "${upTimeArray[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

is returning the following

```
"1\r\n"
"1\r\n"
```

I need it to return just "1" for each line so I can iterate over the array until each equals 2 or greater.

---

**EDIT #2**

I made progress with help provided here but eventually fully solved my issues with the question and scripting in this second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362975/bash-aws-cli-trying-to-figure-out-how-to-validate-an-array-of-uptimes-with-2-ch

Comment: Note that `$my_array` is equivalent to `${my_array[0]}`

Comment: What’s does the output of your `aws ... | jq ...` command look like?

Comment: @bxm the same...I have tried various options with sed to strip the \r\n without success so far.

ws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "$ssmID" --details --output json | jq '.CommandInvocations[].CommandPlugins[].Output'
"1\r\n"
"1\r\n"

Comment: What bxm means is that we don't know what your `aws...` command produces, so we can't recommend anything to process its output. (I'd suggest you add it to your question)

Comment: Are you saying you literally see `\r\n` as visible characters in the response, or are you talking about their non-visible equivalents?

Comment: Output is literally "1\r\n" from AWS CLI in it's standard JSON output mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually enter the loop:

```bsh
$ completeLoop=false
$ while [ ! $completeLoop ]; do date; done; echo complete
complete
```

The `[` command, when given a single argument (setting aside `!` and the trailing `]`), will return success if the argument is not empty. Both "true" and "false" are not empty.

To act on the actual boolean result of `true` and `false` commands, omit `[`:

```bsh
completeLoop=false
count=0
# ....vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
while ! "$completeLoop"; do
  echo in loop
  (( ++count == 5 )) && completeLoop=true
done
echo complete
```

```
in loop
in loop
in loop
in loop
in loop
complete
```

---

You want

```bsh
readarray -t upTimeArray < <(
   aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "$ssmID" --details --output json |
     sed $'s/\r$//' |
     jq -r '.CommandInvocations[].CommandPlugins[].Output'
)
```

Using sed to remove the trailing carriage return (the newline is handled automatically), and `jq -r` to output the "raw" value without quotes.

I'm redirecting from a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) instead of a here-string. Same results.

It's OK to add extra whitespace inside `$(...)` for readability

Comment: Thank you I will dig into this today and do some thorough testing. I think you helped on my last question as well, really appreciate it.

Comment: End of year work is killing me but hopefully I will get to dig into this soon and report back as to whether I was able to solve based on your very well laid out explanation/solution.

Comment: Testing to see if the values in the array are greater than 5 keeps failing on me and I assume it's due to the empty lines in the array?

You can see the line breaks below when I print the array:



: printf '%s\n' "${upTimeArray[@]}"
494

494

Comment: Gave you credit here because your assistance and the assistance in this second question eventually led me to a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362975/bash-aws-cli-trying-to-figure-out-how-to-validate-an-array-of-uptimes-with-2-ch